# rewriting query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

After a db schema change, what was a column is now computed in stored procedure.  Is it possible to make this change seamless for application programs?

So that when a program sends a query like

```
SELECT id, 
       value 
  FROM table
```

...it instead gets a result of

```
SELECT id, 
       compute_value() AS value
  FROM table
```

I thought I could use a RULE, but it is not possible to create SELECT rule on existing table.

So the only other option seems to me to create a new table and a view with the name of the existing one. Which, because of the need for INSERT/UPDATE triggers for the view is too complicated. Then I'd rather update all the client applications.

Comment: Rules are not possible on `SELECT`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createrule.html Have a look at "event": The event is one of SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.

Comment: I wanted "SELECT rule on existing table". Ie. you have a table 'foo' and you want SELECT rule on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you want to return value, you use a function rather than a stored procedure.  Then you'd reference it like:

```
SELECT id,
       your_function_name(parameter) AS value
  FROM TABLE
```

There's [an example under "SQL Functions on Composite Types" in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7/static/xfunc.htm).

Creating a view using the statement above is ideal if your application needs the computed value constantly, otherwise I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Yep, a VIEW is the way to go.